# Multiplicar matrices usando el API de hilos en JAVA

Tags: java, hilos

Nunca he trabajado con hilos y esta será mi primera vez.

**Cómo puedo multiplicar dos matrices usando el API de hilos en JAVA?**

Hasta ahora tengo el código para crear y multiplicar las matrices:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int FILAS =4;
        final int COLUMNAS = 3;
        int [][] a = new int [FILAS][COLUMNAS];
        int [][] b = new int [FILAS][COLUMNAS];
        int [][] c = new int [FILAS][COLUMNAS];

        final int BASE = 1;
        final int RANGO = 10;

        // Llenar matrices
        for (int fila = 0; fila < FILAS; ++fila)
          for (int columna = 0; columna < COLUMNAS ; ++columna){
            a[fila][columna]=(int)(Math.random()*RANGO + BASE);
            b[fila][columna]=(int)(Math.random()*RANGO + BASE);
         }

        // Imprimir matriz 1
        System.out.println("Matriz 1:");
        for (int fila = 0; fila < FILAS ; ++fila){
          for (int columna = 0; columna < COLUMNAS ; ++columna)
           System.out.print (a[fila][columna] + " ");
           System.out.println();
        }

       System.out.println();

        // Imprimir matriz 2
       System.out.println("Matriz 2:");
        for (int fila = 0; fila < FILAS ; ++fila){
          for (int columna = 0; columna < COLUMNAS; ++columna)
           System.out.print (b[fila][columna] + " ");
           System.out.println();
        }

        // Multiplicar matrices
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++) {
                    // Efectuar multiplicación
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // Dibujar matriz resultante
        System.out.println("\nMatriz Resultante:");
        for (int fila=0;fila<FILAS;++fila){
              for (int columna = 0; columna < COLUMNAS ; ++columna)
                  System.out.print (c[fila][columna] + " ");
                  System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. No encuentro ningún ejemplo fácil de entender en internet.

**Qué tengo que hacer para usar hilos?, cómo lo aplico?.**

Answer (score 2):

**La clase Thread**

Es la clase que encapsula todo el control necesario sobre los hilos de ejecución (threads). Hay que distinguir claramente un objeto **Thread** de un hilo de ejecución o thread.

Hay dos modos de conseguir hilos de ejecución (threads) en **Java**. Una es implementando el interfaz **Runnable**, la otra es extender la clase **Thread**.

La implementación del interfaz **Runnable** es la forma habitual de crear hilos. Los interfaces proporcionan al programador una forma de agrupar el trabajo de infraestructura de una clase. Se utilizan para diseñar los requerimientos comunes al conjunto de clases a implementar. El interfaz define el trabajo y la clase, o clases, que implementan el interfaz para realizar ese trabajo. Los diferentes grupos de clases que implementen el interfaz tendrán que seguir las mismas reglas de funcionamiento.

**run()**

El método **run()** constituye el cuerpo de un hilo en ejecución. Este es el único método del interfaz **Runnable**. Es llamado por el método **start()** después de que el hilo apropiado del sistema se haya inicializado. Siempre que el método **run()** devuelva el control, el hilo actual se detendrá.

**LinkedList** y **ArrayList** son dos diferentes implementaciones de la interfaz **List**. **LinkedList** usa internamente una lista doblemente ligada, mientras que **ArrayList** usa un arreglo que cambia de tamaño dinámicamente.

**LinkedList** permite eliminar e insertar elementos en tiempo constante usando iteradores.

**ArrayList** ofrece acceso en tiempo constante O(1), pero si quieres añadir o remover un elemento en cualquier posición que no sea la última es necesario mover elementos. Además si el arreglo ya está lleno es necesario crear uno nuevo con mayor capacidad y copiar los elementos existentes.

Entonces el ejemplo puedes cambiar **LinkedList** por **ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<Thread> hilos = new ArrayList<Thread>();
```

Te dejo el siguiente código bien explicado y entendible realizado por chuidiang:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 *
 * @author chuidiang
 */
public class MultiplicaMatricesConHilos 
{
    /**
     * Crea dos matrices, las multiplica y saca el resultado por pantalla.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Dos matrices para multiplicar 
        double [][] m1 = new double[][] {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
        double [][] m2 = new double[][] {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};

        // Se multiplican
        double [][] resultado = new MultiplicaMatricesConHilos().multiplica(m1, m2);


        // Se saca por pantalla el resultado.
        for (int i=0;i<resultado.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<resultado[0].length;j++)
                System.out.print(resultado[i][j]+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Realiza la multiplicación de las dos matrices y devuelve el resultado
     * @param m1 primer operando
     * @param m2 segundo operando
     * @return resultado de multiplicar m1xm2
     */
    public double[][] multiplica (double [][] m1, double [][] m2)
    {
        // condiciones que deben cumplirse y que se suponen ciertas
        // con los parámetros de entrada
        assert m1!=null;
        assert m2!=null;
        assert m1.length > 0;
        assert m1[0].length > 0;
        assert m2.length > 0;
        assert m2[0].length > 0;
        assert m1.length==m2[0].length;

        // Calculo de las dimensiones de la matriz resultado y
        // reserva de espacio para ella
        int filas = m1.length;
        int columnas = m2[0].length;
        double [][] resultado = new double[filas][columnas];

        // Lista con todos los hilos lanzados.
        LinkedList<Thread> hilos = new LinkedList<Thread>();

        // Para cada elemento de la matriz resultado, se lanza el hilo
        // correspondiente.
        for (int fila=0; fila<filas; fila++)
            for (int columna=0; columna<columnas; columna++)
            {
                Thread hilo = new Thread(
                        new HiloMultiplicador(m1,m2,resultado,fila,columna));
                hilos.add(hilo);
                hilo.start();
            }

        // Se espera que terminen todos los hilos
        for (Thread hilo: hilos)
            try {
                hilo.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // se devuelve el resultado obtenido    
        return resultado;
    }

}

/**
 * Calcula uno de los elementos de la matriz resultado
 * @author chuidiang
 */
class HiloMultiplicador implements Runnable
{
    private double[][] m1;
    private double[][] m2;
    private double[][] resultado;
    private int fila;
    private int columna;

    /**
     * Guarda los parámetros que se le pasan 
     * @param m1 primer operando
     * @param m2 segundo operando
     * @param resultado matriz donde dejar el resultado
     * @param fila fila que debe calcular
     * @param columna columna que debe calcular
     */
    public HiloMultiplicador (double[][] m1, double[][]m2, double[][]resultado, int fila, int columna)
    {
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
        this.resultado = resultado;
        this.fila = fila;
        this.columna = columna;
    }

    /**
     * Calcula el elemento fila,columna de la matriz resultado
     */
    public void run()
    {
        resultado[fila][columna]=0.0;
        for (int i=0;i<m2.length;i++)
            resultado[fila][columna]+=m1[fila][i]*m2[i][columna];
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
run:
6.0 12.0 18.0  
6.0 12.0 18.0  
6.0 12.0 18.0  
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Hola, había visto ese ejemplo en internet pero, no logré comprenderlo. No entiendo el por qué hace un LinkedList, por qué instancia Thread, por qué agrega el hilo al LinkedList, en fin... unas cuantas cosas que no entiendo, recuerda que es mi primera vez con hilos.

Comment: Ya modifique la respuesta ya te explique para que es la clase Thread, quiero pensar que si has trabajado con listas te dejo de todos modos una breve explicación

Comment: Hola, gracias por la explicación pero, hay algo que no entiendo. Cómo es posible que en la función "multiplica" se pueda instanciar a "Thread" si esa clase no extiende de Thread?. Otra pregunta, en el for de esta función se abre un hilo y se ejecuta en cada iteración?, o sea, es un hilo nuevo para cada término de las matrices?.

Comment: Otra pregunta, por qué se usa LinkedList en este ejercicio en lugar de ArrayList?, es decir, cuál es la razón principal?, no hubiera sido lo mismo usar ArrayList?.

Comment: Si puedes ArraList sin problemas obtienes el mismo resultado de hecho en la descripción lo puse y cual es la diferencia de cada uno.

Comment: es un poco viejo el hilo pero pregunto porque tienes el metodo multiplicar matrices en el main?ese metodo no iria en algun otro sitio